# Generating array elements randomly in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to generate a range of values using an array.  I am setting few elements of the array to a variable and the remaining as a constant. In the example below, I am setting the first element as a variable and then using a for loop to generate all possible values of it.

However, it keeps reusing the same value of **a** which it was initialized to. How can I generate a range of values in an array?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    char example[4]={a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
    int i = 0;

    for(a = 0; a < 0x7f; a++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            printf("%x ",example[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep changing the value of a, you need to manually change it in your array (or use a pointer).  Here's the code for manually changing:

```
for(a=0;a<0x7f;a++)
{   
    example[0] = a;

    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        printf("%x ",example[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Otherwise the array holds what you originally set it to.  In c an assignment copies the current value into the new variable, it doesn't set up a reference or a link to the assigned value.  To create a reference that keeps changing as the original variable changes you'd need to use a pointer to `a`.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I misunderstand your code, it will print a sequence of zeros (which is the only data in your array). Your `example` array is initialized *before* the loop, so changing the value of `a` in the loop is not going to affect the array's contents.